# How does a backend application validate a JWT token sent by a JavaScript framework application?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to understand how the [Implicit Flow](https://auth0.com/docs/flows/implicit-flow-with-form-post) works.

[image]

Let's say, the frontend application is Angular and the backend is ASP.NET WEB API. At the end of the process as described in the above screenshot is that my angular application gets a JWT that it stores in browser's the local storage. The token will sent to the API along with every request.

Since no JavaScript application can be trusted, the backend application should validate the token. My question is to know how my API would do that? Will the API need to make a call of its own to the provider to verify that the token is valid?

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This a general answer going by the JWT pattern in a language agnostic way.  The typical way that the backend would validate an incoming JWT from the frontend would be first to check the checksum.  Every JWT has a checksum field which is a sort of hash computed based on the contents of the JWT, using a key which only the server has.  As a first step, the server can compute the checksum and compare against the value in the JWT.  If it *doesn't* match, then the server would immediately reject the JWT on the grounds that its content has been tampered with.

The second step the server might take would be to check the *claims* section of the incoming JWT.  The claims section might look like:

```
{
    sub: "some_user",
    exp: "2020-09-10 00:00:00",
    ...
}
```

The critical claim above is `exp`, which is short for expiration date.  This is the time beyond which the server-issued JWT is no longer valid.  The server would reject an incoming JWT which is past its expiration date.

There are other checks the server might also do.  For example, it might hit a blacklist cache looking for JWTs which have been manually invalidated.

Comment: Do you mean the API won't try to call the IDP to check for itself?

Comment: Forgive me, but _which_ API, and also what does IDP stand for?

Comment: Sorry to be so cryptic. By API, I mean ASP.NET Core Web Api, our backend. And by IDP, I mean the Identity provider we contracted with. When I debug the code, I can see that it making call to the IDP for every request. That's why I'd like to understand whether the trip back to the IDP is necessary, or ASP.NET Core web api (with the right nuget package), can authenticate user with the token that was sent.

Comment: @Richard77 If you already have some IDP microservice which is issuing your JWT tokens, then this microservice is what needs to verify those tokens.